# getting Error for Audio Streaming in Android (using URL)

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

Want to do a audio streaming for a URL. The same URL is playing a live radio while running on the mobile browser. But while using `MediaPlayer` for android app there is no output. It gives the following error.

```
    09-07 05:16:37.539: E/MediaPlayer(1265): error (1, -2147483648)
09-07 05:16:37.539: W/System.err(1265): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

My code sample is :

```
try {
        Log.i("Audio Streaming", "start-->");
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL_OF_AUDIO);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: May be your Live URL is not valid.

Comment: I am not getting the meaning of Live URL. Its playing fine in browser.

Comment: Live URL means Streaming URL.In your LOG data you mentioned java.io.IOException: Prepare failed. check the URL and internet connection of your device.Can u provide URL?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that URL which is passing is valid and check the androidmanifest whether it is having the access permission.

use onprepared listener to start the video to avoid some unwanted exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

try this one it works fine........

```
public class test extends Activity implements OnErrorListener, OnPreparedListener {

private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://www.hubharp.com/web_sound/BachGavotte.mp3");
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer play) {
    play.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    return false;
}
}
```